# DocumentBuilder.parse method returns null using JDK 10 and tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat, dom, xml-parsing, java-10, tomcat9

Recently I have installed tomcat 9 and Open JDK 10. Facing error while parsing InputStream or File or String using DocumentBuilder, I am getting [#document: null].

Please suggest

**UPDATE:**
Here is the scenario I am working on.

```
Document template = convertToFile(xmlData);
System.out.println("template: "+template.item(0).getLength()); -- returns 0

Document convertToFile(String xmlData){

Document templateDoc = docBuilder.parse(xmlData as InputSource);
System.out.println("template: "+template.item(0).getLength()); -- retruns 1

return templateDoc;
}
```

When we are passing the document object to another method / class we are facing trouble getting node data.

Comment: `[#document: null]` is the output of the `Document`’s `toString()` method. It does not mean that the document was `null`.

Comment: Did you have an alternative XML implementation on your class path when you were on JDK 8?

Comment: @AlanBateman, No we are using the same. Does the formation of the document may causing the problem ?

Comment: Can you include a small example to demonstrate what you are seeing.

Comment: @AlanBateman, I have updated my question with sample scenario. Please have a look.

Comment: The question doesn't have the XML input, do you have a small example to include?